# ‘TestFlight Public Link’ feature for Beta Testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, testflight-public-link

As Apple introduce TestFlight Public Link for beta testers im unable to find it and use it. Im new to iTunes please can anyone help me steps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The TestFlight Public Link feature is not currently available. My understanding is that it will become available this summer along with the App Store Connect APIs. These features are listed as "Coming Soon" in the [App Store Connect page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/) of Apple's website.

Comment: still cannot find it

Comment: The public link feature is now visible and usable.

Comment: I have admin access, though I dont get option of `Enable Public Link`

Comment: There's no `Enable Public Link`. It just say that I don't have any build to use public link. Which I do have 9 builds in this group.

Answer (score 19):

To enable your link, you'll need an *Admin* or an *App Manager* role.

You must log in to [AppStore Connect](http://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) > My Apps > Your App. Then, go to the TestFlight Tab and create or select a Group.

Select the desired external tester group and click the button "**Enable Public Link**", where an unique URL is generated.

It is worth mentioning that you can:

- Set a limit for the number of testers that can join a group through your public link;
- Disable the link at anytime.

[image: AppStore Connect TestFlight Public Link screenshot]

Comment: I don't have these side options like WWDC. how u got these?

Comment: As mentioned above, this feature is not currently available. But it was announced at WWDC 2018, a session called [What's New in App Store Connect](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/301/). I found the whole talk to be very interesting, but you can skip to 10' where they mention the Public Link.

Answer (score 9):

I have admin access, though I dont get option of Enable Public Link. It says, I don't have any build to use public link, whereas I have multiple build approved

Comment: I got the option Enable Public Link for one of the group A of my app. Whereas I have put same build in group B, but that still shows the same message that I posted above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942767/testflight-public-link-feature-for-beta-testing#answer-52548089

Answer (score 3):

[The Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) states:

> ## External Testers and Groups
>
> Once you’re ready, you can invite up to 10,000 external testers who do not need to be part of your team. You can invite testers using their email address or enable a shareable public link, which creates an open invitation for anyone to test your app. You can organize external testers into custom groups and share different builds with each group, depending on which features you want them to test. **Before external testing can begin, the beta must pass review to make sure it complies with the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). Only the first build for the beta version requires a full review.**

Which in other words mean, that in order to be able to publish an open beta (at least in the first go), the app needs to have already passed apple's review and have the status of "**ready to submit**" instead of "**Waiting for review**"

Answer (score 1):

After many search finally i got to the point, TestFlight Public Link is not currently available. But will be available end of this summer. Thank You all who post answers.(asked July 2018).

**Note:** Now this option is available on itune.

Comment: I got the option `Enable Public Link` for one of the group A of my app. Whereas I have put same build in group B, but that still shows the same message that I shared above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942767/testflight-public-link-feature-for-beta-testing#answer-52548089

Comment: @SupriyaKalghatgi oh okay finally you found.

Comment: @SupriyaKalghatgi may be this is beta version and on public testing yet. will be soon miss Supriya.

Answer (score 0):

Go to below link for step-by-step instructions on creating groups, inviting testers, and adding builds in TestFlight.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/app-store-connect/101/